# Mysql query to get all different messages for same user

Tags: php, mysql

This a simple chat table

```
id| fromUserId| toUserId| message
```

Let's take dummy data John (45), Jane(46) and Mary(47). Say John chats with both Jane and Mary at the same time.

John (45) started the conversation with Jane (46) so data looks like this:

```
id| fromUserId| toUserId| message
1 | 45        | 46      | wassup?
```

In the second context, Mary (47) started conversation with John (45)

```
id| fromUserId| toUserId| message
2 | 47        | 45      | wassup?
```

How can I display the two different conversations to John? I'm using this query but it does not work:

```
    <?php
        $chatmsgQ="SELECT * FROM ve_chat c 
       WHERE c.isActive='1' AND c.fromUserId='$loginid_session' 
       OR c.toUserId='$loginid_session'";
    $chatmsgresult=  mysqli_query($db,$chatmsgQ);?>
```

**EDIT WITH USAGE**

```
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="overflow-x: hidden;">
      <?php
      $chatmsgQ="SELECT * FROM ve_chat c WHERE c.isActive='1' AND (c.fromUserId='$loginid_session' OR c.toUserId='$loginid_session') GROUP BY (c.fromUserId='$loginid_session' OR c.toUserId='$loginid_session')";
      $chatresultse=  mysqli_query($db,$chatmsgQ);
      while($chatboxes=  mysqli_fetch_array($chatresultse)){;?>
      <li  style="font-size: small; ">
      <a style='width: 100% !important;' href='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#chatModal'>
      Chat  with <?=$chatresultuseres['ProfileName'];?> | <?=$rowChat[0];?> Msg (s)
                </a>
                 </li>
            <?php } ;?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Group the `or`, parameterize the query, and describe what happens. `(c.fromUserId='$loginid_session' 
       OR c.toUserId='$loginid_session')`. It errors, returns the wrong records, returns nothing, etc.

Comment: @chris85: hey chris well right now I only get one conversation with one user to display.

Comment: Are you looping the fetch? Can you add more of you PHP usage?

Comment: @chris85: yes updating right now

Comment: @chris85: So the problem is when I write to John from different users, all the messages goes to same window when I should get 3 different links

Comment: `$chatboxes` is never used. `$chatresultuseres` and `$rowChat` are never defined. This cant work...can it?

Comment: The `group by` is probably your issue but with the provided code i cant see this ever giving back data.

Comment: @chris85: you are right chris im looking at my code right now and it's messed up I will update with everything if you dont mind seeing my mess... I coded it the way I thought it would work

Comment: Take out the `group by` and see what you get first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144214/discussion-between-chris85-and-sebastian-farham).

Comment: @chris85: im cleaning up my code right now before posting an update here. Meanwhile I did remove the group by but I need it to be there to only show one conversation per 2 people.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Parenthesis in your MySQL query

Example :

```
<?php
        $chatmsgQ="SELECT * FROM ve_chat c 
       WHERE c.isActive='1' AND (c.fromUserId='$loginid_session' 
       OR c.toUserId='$loginid_session')";
    $chatmsgresult=  mysqli_query($db,$chatmsgQ);?>
```